# Sodium in canned beans and legumes

Tags: canning, beans, chickpeas, legumes

I was looking at some cans of black beans and chickpeas I had.

They both had higher sodium than I would have expected. Much higher than non-canned varieties.

I am wondering where does that sodium lie? Is the sodium in the liquid that the beans are packaged into? Does the nutritional info take into account the liquid proportionately? Can I rinse them thoroughly to reduce the sodium?

Comment: Read the label. Does it say there's salt added? It used to be commonly added here but not any more. Even when salt was added you could usually find tinned beans without

Comment: You should post a label so we can guess if salt refer to the net or to the drained weight.  In my country is explicitly indicated.

Answer (score 2):

Sodium chloride along with sugar is something that most manufacturers add to their products.

Yes, rinsing will reduce the sodium content.